# ContentResolver.query() Security Exception While Accessing Contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-permissions

I have the following Java code for accessing all the contacts that took part in a conversation based on a specific thread_id. **UPDATE** This code sits in a library that is imported by the application. **DONE UPDATE**

```
private ArrayList<Contact> getContactsFromThreadId(long threadId) {
    ArrayList<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    /** TODO set up projection this is inefficient */
    Cursor allCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);
    String [] info = new String[allCursor.getColumnCount()];
    for( int i = 0; i < allCursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        info[i] = allCursor.getColumnName(i);
    }

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, info, THREAD_ID + threadId, null, SORT_ORDER);
    if (cursor != null) {
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = cursor.getLong(0);
                    String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}; 
                    Cursor contactCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_CONTACTS, projection, USER_ID + id, null, null);
                    String number = "";
                    String name = "";
                    if (contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int numberColumn = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
                        number = contactCursor.getString(numberColumn);
                        int nameColumn = contactCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
                        name = contactCursor.getString(nameColumn);
                    }
                    contacts.add(new Contact(id, number, name));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

When running the code above I catch a SecurityException from the following line:

```
// private final Uri PHONE_CONTACTS = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
Cursor contactCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_CONTACTS, projection, USER_ID + id, null, null);
```

The stack trace reports:

```
07-15 10:11:00.468: W/System.err(20527): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 uri content://contacts from pid=20527, uid=10140 requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

So I added the following to my main manifest file outside of the main activity declaration:

```
<!-- I ADDED THIS LINE -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONCACTS" />
```

**UPDATE**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity...></activity>
```

Comment: Have you also added the "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission?

Comment: @Jade Byfield No I have not, let me try that and see if it fixes the problem. I have added it and I am still getting the security exception.

Comment: Also, is that uses-permission line inside the Application tag?

Comment: No it is not. I will post the relevant parts above to see what I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONCACTS" />`

should be

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

Answer (score 0):

try by changing     `android:targetSdkVersion="14"` or lower than 16

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the problem was to change:

```
private final Uri PHONE_CONTACTS = Uri.parse("content://contacts");
```

To:

```
private final Uri PHONE_CONTACTS = CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
```

And the query from:

```
Cursor contactCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_CONTACTS, projection, USER_ID + id, null, null);
```

To:

```
Cursor contactCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_CONTACTS, null, CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+id, null, SORT_ORDER);
```

And to change the typo in my Manifest file as suggested by Karakuri.